# Is there a way to import a range selected in Excel to my web application?

Tags: excel, jsf, office-js

I'm trying to import a selected range in Excel to my web application (JSF with JavaScript).

I'm already able to import an entire Excel file with file upload and I can also copy content of Excel file, paste it in some kind of text input and parse it afterwards, but I would really love to have the behavior when one excel uses a selected range of another one.

I'm aware that this is maybe not possible because the browser's runtime is separated from the client (which runs Excel) for very good reasons. Nevertheless I just wanted to check if there is a good idea outside which I didn't found in my web search.

**Excel range select:**

[image: excel range select]

Answer (score 0):

You could use [insertWorkbookFromBase64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheetcollection?view=excel-js-preview#addFromBase64_base64File__sheetNamesToInsert__positionType__relativeTo_) API to copy the worksheet from another workbook. and then you could remove the other unrelated content by API call.

Below are the sample code for your reference.

```
async function run() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    //Excel.InsertWorksheetOptions
    var workbook = context.workbook;

    var options = {
      sheetNamesToInsert: ["sample"],
      positionType: Excel.WorksheetPositionType.end,
      relativeTo: "Sheet1"
    };
    const sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
    sheets.addFromBase64(
      workbookContents,
      null, // get all the worksheets
      Excel.WorksheetPositionType.end // insert them after the current workbook's worksheets
    );
    await context.sync();
  });
}

async function getFileBase64() {
  const myFile = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("file");
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = (event) => {
    // strip off the metadata before the base64-encoded string
    const startIndex = reader.result.toString().indexOf("base64,");
    workbookContents = reader.result.toString().substr(startIndex + 7);
  };

  // read in the file as a data URL so we can parse the base64-encoded string
  reader.readAsDataURL(myFile.files[0]);
}

async function insertWorksheetsFromBase64(workbookContents) {
  Excel.run((context) => {
    //Excel.InsertWorksheetOptions
    var options = { sheetNamesToInsert: [], positionType: Excel.WorksheetPositionType.before, relativeTo: "Sheet2" };

    const sheets = context.workbook.insertWorksheetsFromBase64(workbookContents);
    return context.sync();
  });
}
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but the Excel-JavaScript-API works only inside excel (and the corresponding Addin) and does not provide any direct interface to a website, does it? The main benefit for my use case would be the user beeing able to select a range in excel with the already known functionality and this range beeing directly imported to the website (javascript).